# Matrix to be read from and written to from out of any class

Tags: java, matrix

I'm running a Java program with over 60 classes. The most important item is a `matrix[210][20]` that is read from and written to several different classes.
At this moment the matrix is passed as a parameter to the classes that need access to it. As far as I'm aware, I believe this causes the memory space for this matrix to be doubled.
Now I need to add 3 more matrices which are even larger (`[1390][20]`), so I'm afraid to get in trouble (memory usage at this moment is already +/- 50% !).
I'm convinced there should be a nicer way to handle this, I looked around and tried but always got stuck and can't get it right.
Please advise!

Comment: Is it possible to make the matrix static (or provide a static getter method), so you can access it without passing it as a parameter?

Comment: "As far as I'm aware, I believe this causes the memory space for this matrix to be doubled." - how much do you know about objects and references?

Comment: How big are the values in the matrix? A 1390*20 matrix of long values should only take up about 217kb - which shouldn't be a problem unless operating in a constrained environment.

Comment: icke : matrix values change during program run, so static isn't an option; immibis : apparently not enough ... ; robert : values are doubles.

Comment: @Veronique `static` does not mean `final`. `static` only means that the field does not belong to one instance, but is shared among all instances of a class. `final` means that you can’t reassign the field. But you can reassign a `static` field.

Comment: @Veronique doubles are the same size as `long`; making an array `final` does not prevent you from modifying it's contents. It is only the reference itself that is immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veronique, I think in looking at the matrix, you are looking at the wrong place.

A matrix of `double`, as I mentioned should not take up an inordinate amount of space.

Even if it were a matrix of objects, you would still be better off looking at the objects themselves, rather than the matrix, and maybe employing something like a [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

At this point I believe your best bet is to actually examine what is happening when the program is running, rather than guessing based on your own analysis.

For this you should investigate using a tool like [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html), which should expose memory consumption hotspots of this magnitude very quickly.

FYI a common cause of memory leaks in java is references to old objects hanging around in `Collections` such as `Map` and `List` so I'd suggest you check there. Also see if you are creating duplicate instances of your matrix object (which would in fact use up your memory quite quickly after a few thousand copies :).

Comment: Heap of my program has only 17MB, i have other open java applications that are taking much more space, so i guess i should not be worried about my own application, as you already mentioned. Thanks for your help anyway, this jvisualvm is a nice tool !

Answer (score 1):

In Java, method arguments (at least objects) are passed by reference, so your design pattern shouldn’t necessarily cause resource leaks. Nevertheless, you can use a static field to store the variable and write a static accessor:

```
public final class Matrix {

    private static final Object[][] matrix = new Object[1390][20];

    static {
        // fill matrix if necessary
    }

    public static Object[][] getMatrix() {
        return matrix;
    }

}
```

Then use `Matrix.getMatrix()` in your code. Keep in mind that this could cause problems if you access the matrix from different threads.

Comment: This isn't necessary, since such values are passed by reference, not by value. There should only ever be one copy anyway unless explicitly copied.

Comment: Thanks Robin, but i can't use static cause matrix values change all the time. I also have different threads, although i should be able to manage this so that every thread uses only 1 matrix, and uses only a matrix that isn't currently used by another thread.

Comment: @Veronique you can change the values of a static field.

Comment: I don't think you can access instance field from static method. I think you wanted to make that array static.